# Java vanClass giving cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I have code that has several classes with different cars and some classes. Below is my code, I'm not sure why vanClass van; is not working as it is basically a copy paste of the past classes that work. Any help is appreciated. To clarify, I am only having problems with the last few lines of the autopark class where I initiate vanClass as van and go from there.

```
import java.util.*;

class sedan {
    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    boolean isheavyDuty;
    String carries;

    public sedan(String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice) {
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = "Sedan";
        String main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        return main;
    }
}

class SUV {

    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    String carries;

    public SUV(String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initFourWD){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        fourWD = initFourWD;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = "SUV";
        String main = new String();
        if (fourWD) {
            main = ("4WD " + color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        }
        else {
            main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        }

        return main;
    }
}

class truckClass {

    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    boolean isheavyDuty;
    String carries;

    public truckClass(String initMake, String initModel, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initisheavyDuty, String initCarries){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        isheavyDuty = initisheavyDuty;
        carries = initCarries;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = "Truck";
        String main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price);
        return main;
    }

class vanClass {

    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean isCovered;
    String carries;

    public vanClass(String initMake, String initModel, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initisCovered, String initCarries){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        isCovered = initisCovered;
        carries = initCarries;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name;
        String main;
        if (isCovered()){
            name = "covered Van";
            String main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price);
        }
        else {
            name = "Van";
            String main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price);
        }
        return main;
    }
}






public class autoPark {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sedan sedan1; // declaring cars object by name sedan1
        sedan1 = new sedan("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000); // initialising sedan1 using sedan constructor
        System.out.println(sedan1); // printing sedan1 for invoking toString() method

        SUV suv; // declaring cars object by name suv
        suv = new SUV("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000, true); // initialising suv using SUV constructor
        System.out.println(suv); // printing suv for invoking toString() method

        truckClass truck; //declaring cars object by name truck
        truck = new truckClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 20000, true, "2"); // initialising truck using truck constructor
        System.out.println(truck); // printing truck for invoking toString() method

        vanClass van;
        van = new vanClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 20000, true, "2";
        System.out.println(van);


    }
}
```

Comment: you are missing a closing bracket right before starting vanClass. You should learn about inheritance (most of your code can be re-used, instead of duplicated) and naming conventions, it makes your code much easier to read

Comment: Wow, what a silly mistake. Thank you!

Comment: Java coding conventions have classes starting with upper case letters (Truck), while methods and variables start with lower case letters. This would allow you to use 'Truck' rather than 'truckClass' because the upper case letter already tells you that it is a class.

Answer (score 2):

I came across 4 issues

1. missing } just before starting `vanClass`
2. missing ) after `van = new vanClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 20000, true, "2");`
3. extra pair of parenthesis after `isCovered` which is a member data instead of method
4. Declaring `main` as String twice inside the `toString` method of `SUV` class

```java
import java.util.*;

class sedan {
    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    boolean isheavyDuty;
    String carries;

    public sedan(String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice) {
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String name = "Sedan";
        String main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        return main;
    }
}

class SUV {

    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    String carries;

    public SUV(String initMake, String initModel, String initColor, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initFourWD){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        color = initColor;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        fourWD = initFourWD;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = "SUV";
        String main = new String();
        if (fourWD) {
            main = ("4WD " + color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        }
        else {
            main = (color + " " + make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price);
        }

        return main;
    }
}

class truckClass {

    String make;
    String model;
    String color;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean fourWD;
    boolean isheavyDuty;
    String carries;

    public truckClass(String initMake, String initModel, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initisheavyDuty, String initCarries){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        isheavyDuty = initisheavyDuty;
        carries = initCarries;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = "Truck";
        String main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price);
        return main;
    }
}

class vanClass {

    String make;
    String model;
    int year;
    double price;
    boolean isCovered;
    String carries;

    public vanClass(String initMake, String initModel, int initYear, double initPrice, boolean initisCovered, String initCarries){
        make = initMake;
        model = initModel;
        year = initYear;
        price = initPrice;
        isCovered = initisCovered;
        carries = initCarries;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name;
        String main;
        if (isCovered){
            name = "covered Van";
            main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price);
        }
        else {
            name = "Van";
            main = (make + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price);
        }
        return main;
    }

}

public class autoPark {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sedan sedan1; // declaring cars object by name sedan1
        sedan1 = new sedan("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000); // initialising sedan1 using sedan constructor
        System.out.println(sedan1); // printing sedan1 for invoking toString() method

        SUV suv; // declaring cars object by name suv
        suv = new SUV("Ford" , "Model-1" , "white" , 2015, 20000, true); // initialising suv using SUV constructor
        System.out.println(suv); // printing suv for invoking toString() method

        truckClass truck; // declaring cars object by name truck
        truck = new truckClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 20000, true, "2"); // initialising truck using truck constructor
        System.out.println(truck); // printing truck for invoking toString() method

        vanClass van;
        van = new vanClass("Ford" , "Model-1" , 2015, 20000, true, "2");
        System.out.println(van);

    }
}
```

You need to consider using inheritance as mentioned by others.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed and refactored your class using inheritance:

```
abstract class Vehicle{
    protected String maker;
    protected String model;
    protected int year;
    protected double price;

    public Vehicle(String maker, String model, int year, double price) {
        this.maker=maker;
        this.model=model;
        this.year=year;
        this.price=price;
    }

    abstract String getType();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return maker + " " + model + " " + getType() + " (" + year + ") costs $" + price;
    }
}

abstract class HeavyVehicle extends Vehicle{
    protected String carries;

    public HeavyVehicle(String maker, String model, int year, double price, String carries) {
        super(maker, model, year, price);
        this.carries=carries;
    }
}

class SUV extends HeavyVehicle{

    String color;
    boolean fourWD;

    public SUV(String maker, String model, String initColor, int year, double price,
        boolean initFourWD) {
        super(maker,model,year,price,"1");
        color = initColor;
        fourWD = initFourWD;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (fourWD) {
            sb.append("4WD ");
        }
        sb.append(color + " " + super.toString());
        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    String getType() {
        return "SUV";
    }
}

class Truck extends HeavyVehicle{

    public Truck(String maker, String model, int year, double price,String carries) {
        super(maker,model,year,price,carries);
    }

    public String toString() {
        return maker + " " + model + " " + getType() + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price;
    }

    @Override
    String getType() {
        return "Truck";
    }
}

class Van extends HeavyVehicle{

    boolean isCovered;

    public Van(String maker, String model, int year, double price, boolean isCovered, String carries){
        super(maker,model,year,price,carries);
        this.isCovered = isCovered;

    }

    public String toString() {
        String name = isCovered ? "covered Van" : getType();
        return maker + " " + model + " " + name + " (" + year + ") carries" + carries + " costs $" + price;
    }

    @Override
    String getType() {
        return "Van";
    }
}


class Sedan extends Vehicle{
    String color;

    public Sedan(String maker, String model, String color, int year, double price) {
        super(maker,model,year,price);
        this.color = color;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return color + " " + super.toString();
    }

    @Override
    String getType() {
        return "Sedan";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Sedan sedan1; // declaring cars object by name sedan1
        sedan1 = new Sedan("Ford", "Model-1", "white", 2015, 20000); // initialising sedan1 using sedan constructor
        System.out.println(sedan1); // printing sedan1 for invoking toString() method

        SUV suv; // declaring cars object by name suv
        suv = new SUV("Ford", "Model-1", "white", 2015, 20000, true); // initialising suv using SUV constructor
        System.out.println(suv); // printing suv for invoking toString() method

        Truck truck; // declaring cars object by name truck
        truck = new Truck("Ford", "Model-1", 2015, 20000, "2"); // initialising truck using truck constructor
        System.out.println(truck); // printing truck for invoking toString() method

        Van van;
        van = new Van("Ford", "Model-1", 2015, 20000, true, "2");
        System.out.println(van);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Was missing a } and ). Silly mistake